# Where can I see the site's statistics?

Tags: support, statistics

Back when we were still in beta, if I visit the site's home page I can see the statistics (number of questions, number of users, like the table on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3924/unix-linux)).

UL is out of beta now, and it looks like Area 51 has stopped updating statistics for UL. If I want to see the current statistics, is there a URL, or anything accessible online that let me view it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an API route called [`/stats`](http://api.unix.stackexchange.com/1.1/stats) that shows `total_questions` and `total_users`. I don't remember what the other Area 51 stats were on the homepage, but they're probably on `/stats` somewhere

Comment: That link now leads to a page that says, "On May 12th 2014, the API v1.0 and v1.1 endpoints were shutdown."