# Detailed site statistics

Tags: discussion, feature-request, statistics

Is there anywhere we can see detailed site statistics (more so than the API in [this answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/454/where-can-i-see-the-sites-statistics))?

The sorts of stats that I was curious about were things that provide some insight into how the site is functioning, ie., not traffic analytics but social ones, like:

- Percentage of questions closed as "Unclear what you are asking" that are tagged [ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu)
- Percentage of questions asked by people with no rep that are closed for any reason
- Percentage of questions closed as "Unclear what you are asking" that are voted to be reopened after at least one edit

Comment: You can probably get all this from the [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @terdon Never knew it existed: thanks. You should include that as answer. I can't write SQL queries so I can't answer any of the example questions but you have answered my primary question.

Comment: If you ever get round to writing any of these queries or if you find one that does it already, it'd be great if you could post back here. These would be useful stats to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of these can probably be extracted using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/):

> …an open source tool for running arbitrary queries against public data from the Stack Exchange network. Features include collaborative query editing and OData endpoints for all graduated and public beta Stack Exchange sites.

While this is not a particularly user friendly tool, it is designed by and for geeks, it is very well implemented and editing existing queries is simple enough. There are currently 225,631 queries so you are quite likely to find something that is close to what you are looking for.